# Xamarin.forms (or) xamarin.ios/xamarin.android (or) Native

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We are developing an app in our organization where we have to implement charts,maps,GPS, If we Develop in Xamarin.ios/xamrin.android  can developers able to share business logic of the app? since both android/ios projects will be in c#.

Comment: If your app relies heavily on features like the ones you listed: maps, gps, advanced graphical control, then I strongly recommend not using xamarin.forms. Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android seem like the optimum choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing exactly the same thing.

Do not use Xamarin Forms.  It is not designed for nor capable of doing heavily customised UIs.

If you are going to require integration with Maps and also producing any kind of non-standard rendering or "User Controls" Xamarin.Forms is not going to work for you.

Go down the route of using a framework like MvvmCross to further abstract away the platforms and keep your core code / logic and user experience flow within the realms of a Core.Pcl type library.

Also I wouldn't try doing this on Windows 7 based bachines if you are doing this on Windows.  Most of the components you will find yourself wanting to use will be targetting Profile259 and since Windows 7 doesn't support Windows Phone 8 you'll have all manner of oddities, even if you do the Profile259 hack.

Go with [MvvmCross](http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/), Windows 8 and ignore Xamarin Forms.

I wrote a bit of it up on [my blog](http://www.jammer.biz/xamarin-the-baptism-of-fire-windows-7/).

[Read this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/offline.pdf) from Xmarin, they clearly state that Forms is for run of the mill business apps or for prototyping.  It's not mature enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write your core app logic (services, data, domain, etc) in a PCL library that is shared by both your Android and iOS apps.

Comment: So you are recommending Xamarin.Forms  (or) xamarin.ios/xamrin.android ?

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic on SO.  Your question specifically asked whether or not you could share code between Xamarin Android and iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can build **most** apps in Xamarin Forms. The main hurdle is that doing anything not included in X.Forms requires that you write Custom Renderers. The thing is, writing custom renderers is much more straightforward if you have a solid grasp of vanilla Xamarin (Xamarin.iOS & Xamarin.Android).

What I think happens is that developers getting into Xamarin go directly to Xamarin.Forms and then become frustrated when they are unable to write custom renderers to accomplish some custom requirements.

So my recommendation is that if you have experience building apps using Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Forms is awesome for getting an application developed rapidly for multiple platforms. Being able to use MVVM + XAML + Data Binding is a huge win.

If you are new to Xamarin or even mobile development, build the app using Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.